# How am I affected by malware? Malware transferred from service provider's base station or just port scan?

Tags: malware, ports, phone

I need a malware expert here. I am being targeted by advanced hackers over the 4.5 years.

So this is my situation:
1) My new phone:
I just bought a new phone, with SIM card and mobile internet plan of 2GB per month. I don't switch on the mobile data all the time (only mobile phone signal is on all the time), even if I do, only about 2 minutes long at one same; only the beginning when I download apps from Google Play I switched on for a long time. I used different SIM card from my previous affected phone, but with the same number (and same internet plan). Didn't download anything else other than apps from Google Play, didn't connect to any WiFi. I ignored any updates because I know people can use the femtocell to trick me. How is it possible for my phone to have malware? Did the malware was transferred to my service provider's base station from my affected phone and transferred back to my new phone through the same number (same identity code)? Is it possible?

2) my new laptop was also affected, I used broadband aka USB modem (so no Wifi is being discovered around) with the same service provider as my phone. Did the malware actually transferred to my new laptop from the service provider's same base station?

Secondly, what exactly port scan is? Does port scan related to malware attack? Does an attacker able to port scan in an isolated connection? Does port scan requires to find a vulnerability that needs your permission to attack?
 ///#1 Does an attacker able to port scan to my new phone through mobile signal and/or mobile internet plan? (on my situation above (1))
 ///#2 Does an attacker able to port scan to my new laptop through my broadband of an isolated connection?

If my situation is not port scan, is it a mobile service provider's base station transferring that I imagined? I thought the mobile base station transferring needs a vulnerability. I am 100% sure it is affected by malware, it probably been affected in a short period time, how is that possible?

Did the malware was transferred to my service provider's base station from my affected phone and transferred back to my new phone and new laptop since there both are from the same service provider?

edit: I also physically lock my phone so nobody can physical access it.

Comment: So you haven't updated the security on your phone and you are wondering how you got malware?

Comment: I wasn't talking about anti-virus security, I was talking about OS system security.

Comment: Also, how are you "100% sure" you have malware?

Comment: @dfree, if you think you are being stalked electronically, you need to contact the police in your jurisdiction. We can't help you. And the scenario you are describing sounds highly improbable.

Comment: ColorOS is based on KitKat. If you do not update it, then you are open to known vulnerabilities. That's what I mean by system security.

Comment: Here's the problem: you've asked a very simple question, "can malware be automatically downloaded to my phone and laptop from my ISP's hardware?" The answer is simple: no. But you've raised so many other issues that might be the real problem. If you want help, you'll have to talk about those things.

Comment: dfree - you need to read and thoroughly digest our [about] and [help] and [ask] pages, otherwise your questions will be closed like this one for making no sense.

Answer (score 2):

First, a port scan is simply an external scan of your computer's ports. This happens all the time and is not automatically an indication of anything. Yes, your laptop is being scanned right now if it has a direct connection to the Internet.

Malware doesn't automatically download to your phone and laptop from your ISP.